# How to make this forest cube?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I am not new to blender, but I am also not a master. I have a project I am working on for a family business, and I am trying to make a cube forest in Blender. However, I have no idea of how to do this.

I am taking inspiration from this image:

[image: Cubic forest, you will need to see it.]

So I am wondering how would I go about this? Are there any tutorials I could follow?

The companies name: Tropical Carbon.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create a cube and sculpt (here a quick try), then you can bake the normals:

[image]